# Generate List of Unique Four-Digit Numbers Without Repeating Digits and Without Forward-Sequential Digits

Tags: php, function

I had a need to generate a list of four-digit numbers for use as codes. The digits should not repeat, and each next digit should not be sequential. There were some questions that were similar but not enough for me to answer. I chose to share my function instead. It did not matter if reverse numbers were in the list e.g. 1357 > 7531.

It occurred to me that it there may be an opportunity for a recursive function, possibly to return five or six-digit numbers. Improvements to my function are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function codeList() {
  $data = [];
  for ($ii=0; $ii < 10; $ii++) {
    for ($jj=0; $jj < 10; $jj++) {
      for ($kk=0; $kk < 10; $kk++) {
        for ($ll=0; $ll < 10; $ll++) {
          $str = "{$ii}{$jj}{$kk}{$ll}";
          $arr = str_split($str);
          if (count($arr) === count(array_unique($arr))) {
            if (($arr[0] + 1 != $arr[1]) && ($arr[1] + 1 != $arr[2]) && ($arr[2] + 1 != $arr[3])) {
              $data[] = $str;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return $data;
} # END FUNCTION codeList
```